# XLabs Forms - Xamarin Studio 6.02 - Cannot add key

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying something extremely simple. A XAML form with an ImageButton, from XLabs.Forms.
If I try to add the package to the IOS app, I get the following error:
An item with the same key has already been added
when adding the XLabs.Platform.
This seems to be a known issue, but I cannot find the next step.
This is described very well [here](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/issues/1220) but I the workaround suggested doesn't work.